# ubuntu disappeared from boot list after update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a dual booted XPS13 9380 with windows 10 and ubuntu 18.4.4. After not using ubuntu for a while I booted back into it and updated (NOT to 20.4). I then updated my installation of Pop_OS! on an sd card, and after doing so I was no longer able to boot into ubuntu:

- GRUB does not show when I boot
- ubuntu is no longer an option in the boot sequence in the BIOS

I have tried to reinstall Ubuntu a couple of times but it still doesn't show as a bootable option, even though I think it is installed (in the ubuntu installer I have the option to "delete ubuntu 18.4.4 and reinsatll").

I have also tried `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` but that only broke my windows boot so I reverted it to `\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi`.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

the problem seems to be that it wasn't booting in UEFI mode, so I added a boot entry for the usb, and reinstalled from there. Working smoothly now

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-)